# Laravel custom collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Need your help. 
I have a view with 6 tabs, two main tabs and three inside each of the mains tabs, i am passing almost the same data in each of the tabs, i only change the status and role.

like this:

Role 1 has three tabs: all tasks | tasks in progress | finished tasks

Role 2 has three tabs: all tasks | tasks in progress | finished tasks

right now i am passing the data in arrays, why... because i didn't find a way of doing it with a collection. but since i cannot loop through a "column" of an array, it means that i should pass 6 arrays, one for each tab. rendering this page is getting slow, and it will get worst with time.

here's one of the arrays:

```
$designersAllTasks = array();
    foreach ($designersTasks as $designerTask)
    {
    $designersAllTasks[] = array(
        'id' => ($designerTask->id),
        'task_type' => (DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $designerTask->task_type_id)->value('task_type')),
        'task_code' => (DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $designerTask->task_type_id)->value('task_code')),
        'chapter_type' => (DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $designerTask->related_block)->value('type')),
        'chapter' => (DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $designerTask->related_block)->value('description')),
        'assigned_to' => (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', $designerTask->assigned_to)->value('display_name')),
        'task_time' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $designerTask->id)->pluck('task_time')->sum()),
        'start_date' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $designerTask->id)->where('status','=','In Progress')->pluck('created_at')->first()),
        'due_date' => ($designerTask->due_date),
        'status' => ($designerTask->status),
        'comments' => ($designerTask->comments),
   );
};
```

So i am trying to do it with a collection, but till now i didn't find a correct way of doing it.

Here's how i am trying to do a collection, obviously the wrong way....

```
$allTasks = new Collection();
     foreach ($tasks as $task)
     {
         $allTasks = collect(
         [
         'id' => ($task->id),
         'task_type' => (DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $task->task_type_id)->value('task_type')),
         'task_code' => (DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $task->task_type_id)->value('task_code')),
         'chapter_type' => (DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $task->related_block)->value('type')),
         'chapter' => (DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $task->related_block)->value('description')),
         'assigned_to' => (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', $task->assigned_to)->value('display_name')),
         'role' => (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', $task->assigned_to)->value('role')),
         'task_time' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->pluck('task_time')->sum()),
         'start_date' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->where('status','=','In Progress')->pluck('created_at')->first()),
         'finished_in' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->where('status','=','Finished')->value('created_at')),
         'due_date' => ($task->due_date),
         'status' => ($task->status),
         'comments' => ($task->comments),
      ]
     );
 };
```

if i do `{{ dd($allTasks) }}`, it returns:

```
Collection {#334 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

how can i do a foreach that for each loop it adds a line to my collection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What you're doing here is wrong, and it's not the solution you need. Please can you change your question to cover your original problem (why you cannot use Eloquent on this specific set of data) and then we can help you solve it properly :)

Comment: even if you returned something, i would guess it would only be the last $task since you're overwriting $allTasks on each iteration

Comment: Instead of `$allTasks = collect([...])` do `$allTasks->push([...])`

Answer (score 2):

While your question is tough to figure out, perhaps, assuming it is even what you are asking, will get you back on track.

```
$allTasks = new Collection();

$tasks = array(
    [
        'id' => 1, 
        'task' => 'go to the store', 
        'task_type' => 'errand', 
        'comments' => 'no fun'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2, 
        'task' => 'drink beer', 
        'task_type' => 'not an errand', 
        'comments' => 'fun'
    ]);

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $allTasks->push(([
        'id' => $task['id'], 
        'task_type' => $task['task_type'], 
        'comments' => $task['comments']
        ]));
}
```

---

```
dd($allTasks);

Collection {#518 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "task_type" => "errand"
      "comments" => "no fun"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "task_type" => "not an errand"
      "comments" => "fun"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Keep in mind i have no clue what your database data is returning, so i created some test data there, but it should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```php
/** @var User $user */
$user = Auth::user();
```

also, I coded about Entity Relation

```php
/** @var User $user */
$user = Auth::user();

//$userBios = $user->bios; // no use like this
$userBios = $user->bios()->get();
```